# why dimen values are showing as error on android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I tried to develop new mobile application for my final project. So here on my android studio in values I want to put new dimen values. But unfortunately there is co dimen.xml on my android studio. So I creates new value resource file for dimen.xml.
Then I wrote this code in my dimen.xml.
But unfortunately dimen sizes shows me as error (red color) Can anyone help me to clear out this code?
Here I attached the pic of the error one?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put in the value between the dimen tags.
Instead of typing:

```
<dimen name="header">@dimen/_10sdp</dimen>
```

Type in:

```
<dimen name="header">10sdp</dimen>
```

You can then access the value in another xml file by typing in:

```
@dimen/header
```

If you want to access the value programmatically, you can type in:

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.header);
```

Comment: Sebi Thank you very much.